# mouseenter function to select the current div(this div)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Following divs are getting generated by ajax.

```
<div id="row1" class="table_row">
<span class="th1">1</span>
<span class="th2">Crocin</span>
<span class="th3">0</span>
</div>

<div id="row2" class="table_row alternate">
<span class="th1">2</span>
<span class="th2">Anacin</span>
<span class="th3">0</span>
</div>
```

I am using the following jQuery to highlight the div that I am pointing to.

```
$(document).on({
                mouseenter : function () {

                    $(this).find('.table_row').addClass('highlight');
                },

                mouseleave : function () {
                    $(this).find('.table_row').removeClass('highlight');
                }
            }, ".table_body");
```

Problem is, it highlights both the divs. I want only the div that I am pointing to be highlighted.

Both these divs are generated inside a parent div having class 'table_body'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target the row then:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    }
}, ".table_body .table_row");
```

Sidenote: could be shortened to:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.table_body .table_row', function(e) {
     $(this).toggleClass('highlight', e.type==='mouseenter');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great optimization. Thanks a lot adeneo and @Barmar.